# How to fix undefined index error with HTTP parameters?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, http, post

I have some code in PHP 5. The code is simple - get data from a form in the site using ajax, and send it to mail.

But the code doesn't get the parameters from the POST call.

I have tried it in Postman and the code still doesn't read the parameters.

Image of Postman:

[image: The call]

[image: The result]

The code in short:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
```

What's the problem?

**EDIT:**

I've changed the code from `$_POST` to `$_GET` - now it working in Postman, but in ajax the error still here,
The ajax (with Jquery):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://doodlevideo.co.il/php/form-process.php",
        data: {name: name_val, email: email_val, msg_subject: msg_subject_val, msg_subject_option: msg_subject_option_val, message: message_val},
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "send"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ther errors point to lines that you didn't wrote on you post. Try using "The code in long"

Comment: That url in the first image looks like it needs a `$_GET`, not a `$_POST`, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Whats your js look like? Are you sure your doing a POST not a GET. Are you using any frame works?